# !property returns true even though it has value assigned

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I check whether a property has a value, including `0`?

The user is allowed to input 0 inside of an input. This value is being assigned to a property. Now if I check for `!this.value`, it returns `true`, even though it's `0`. How so?

```
console.log(this.value) <--- returns 0
if (!this.value) {
  //is being executed
}
```

Comment: `!0` is `true` in JavaScript.  What is the declared type of `this.value`?  When you say "has a value" you mean "not `undefined`"?  If so then check `if (this.value !== undefined)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if(this.value || this.value === 0)
```

you can use if there is value and it is not zero.